# Vue3 and vite build shows blank page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, build, vite

I am working on a vite vue 3 project. Project runs fine in the local development environment. But its build shows blank page. The command used to take this build is `npm run build`.

vite.config.js file is as follows:

```
import {
  defineConfig
} from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

import path from 'path' 
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  define: {
    'process.env': {}
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  base: './',

})
```

Comment: `npm run build` generates a dist folder that must be hosted by an HTTP server.  it doesn't generate an app that can run over `file://` protocol, i.e. you can't just open `index.html` if that's what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

To fix that, you will need to configure your production server to fallback to index.html for any requests that do not match a static file.

(May be) The easiest way to do it is to add something like

```
FallbackResource index.html
```

The Vue  Router docs provides configuration instructions for common server setups
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations